# Interpolation of the divergence

Tags: scipy, interpolation, numeric, numerical-methods, numerical-analysis

I have a prescribed velocity field on a uniform, collocated 2D grid. I need to compute the divergence of the velocity field at some **arbitrary** points that does not coincide with the grid points or midpoint location.

On posibility could be to compute the divergence on the grid points and then interpolate using bicubic interpolation at the unknown points. I am not sure this is a good idea because it could create some checkerboard effect.

I wonder if there is a better way to do that.

I am using python/scipy.

Comment: Another way is to fit a spline to the data, and compute the divergence based on the derivatives of the spline (splines are piecewise polynomials -> their derivatives are known exactly, so the imprecision comes from the spline fit).